# Refactoring Joins with temporal table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like:

```
-- --JOIN one
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT TT.TAXAMOUNT,TT.TAXCODE,TT.TAXITEMGROUP,TT.VOUCHER,TT.TAXORIGIN, TTF.SOURCERECID
FROM TAXTRANS TT
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTABLE TAX ON TAX.PAYMENTTAXCODE = TT.TAXCODE AND TAX.DATAAREAID = 'vb'
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANS TTF ON TAX.TAXCODE = TTF.TAXCODE AND TTF.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE = TT.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE
WHERE TT.TRANSDATE between @FECHA_INI AND @FECHA   
AND TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND ("+@Codigo_IEPSCUOTAP_TT+")) TTIEPSCUOTA ON 
C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPSCUOTA.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXITEMGROUP
AND PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPSCUOTA.SOURCERECID 


 --JOIN two
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT TT.TAXAMOUNT,TT.TAXCODE,TT.TAXITEMGROUP,TT.VOUCHER,TT.TAXORIGIN, TTF.SOURCERECID
FROM TAXTRANS TT
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTABLE TAX ON TAX.PAYMENTTAXCODE = TT.TAXCODE AND TAX.DATAAREAID = 'vb'
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANS TTF ON TAX.TAXCODE = TTF.TAXCODE AND TTF.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE = TT.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE
WHERE TT.TRANSDATE between @FECHA_INI AND @FECHA
AND TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND ("+@Codigo_IEPS25P_TT+")) TTIEPS25 ON 
C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPS25.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPS25.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPS25.SOURCERECID
```

As you can see `Join one` and  `Join two` are the same join except for 4 last lines, so I decided to create a temp table to call select just one time like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TTC' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TTC 
GO


SELECT * INTO ##TTC FROM (
SELECT
TT.TAXAMOUNT,
TT.TAXCODE,
TT.TAXITEMGROUP,
TT.VOUCHER,
TT.TAXORIGIN,
TT.SOURCERECID,
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTABLE TAX ON TAX.PAYMENTTAXCODE = TT.TAXCODE AND TAX.DATAAREAID = 'vb'
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANS TTF ON TAX.TAXCODE = TTF.TAXCODE AND TTF.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE = TT.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE
WHERE TT.TRANSDATE between @FECHA_INI AND @FECHA   
AND TT.TAXORIGIN = 11
GO
```

Now I have all select into my table, now I want to know how can implement my temporal table with last 4 lines of query, can someone help? Regards

Comment: What database server is this for?  Also is the result you want a union of the two?  Or should the two joins relate as aliases of taxtrans?

Comment: sql server 2012, but I´m immplementing on SSIS project  as OLEDB Task,I do temporal table because these two uses same select, and that select have 500 millions of registers, so I want to call just one time saving into temporal table, now I want to do the same as I have at original but using temporal table instead select because first six lines of my query are into my temp table@DanielGimenez

Comment: What about the output, is it just a union of the two or are they joined?

Comment: You can convert subquery to view, and use it on left joins

Comment: I can´t create view, I need to keep same structure of query, I just want to replace first six lines of each join with temporal table and merge with last 4 with my temp table, is that possible? @sarslan

Comment: If it is possible you can use `Common Table Expression` instead of view ?

Comment: yes I can @sarslan

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
;WITH TTC AS
(SELECT TT.TAXAMOUNT,TT.TAXCODE,TT.TAXITEMGROUP,TT.VOUCHER,TT.TAXORIGIN, TTF.SOURCERECID
FROM TAXTRANS TT
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTABLE TAX ON TAX.PAYMENTTAXCODE = TT.TAXCODE AND TAX.DATAAREAID = 'vb'
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANS TTF ON TAX.TAXCODE = TTF.TAXCODE AND TTF.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE = TT.SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE
WHERE TT.TRANSDATE between @FECHA_INI AND @FECHA   
AND TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND ("+@Codigo_IEPSCUOTAP_TT+"))

-- MAIN TABLE
-- --JOIN one
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
TTC TTIEPSCUOTA ON 
C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPSCUOTA.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXITEMGROUP
AND PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPSCUOTA.SOURCERECID 


 --JOIN two
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
TTC TTIEPS25 ON 
C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPS25.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPS25.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPS25.SOURCERECID
```

Comment: and without CTE, we can call temporal table or no?

Comment: without cte, you don't have any other alternative.

Comment: I think I just can use `(SELECT * FROM ##TTC WHERE ("+@Codigo_IEPSCUOTAP_TT+")) TTIEPSCUOTA ON` ... etc